# Using scipy package, which sequence to choose for Rotation.as_euler()

Tags: scipy, quaternions, euler-angles, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to convert from quaternion to row pitch yaw using the as_euler() function, but I don't know which sequence to choose as the parameter "zyx", "xyz", "zyz", etc

Also what is the order of the output euler angles? Is it going to be [roll, pitch yaw] or [yaw, pitch, roll]?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yaw, pitch, roll axes are used for rotation around its principal axis sequentially.  there exist twelve possible sequences which are;

Proper Euler Angles "z-x-z, x-y-x, y-z-y, z-y-z, x-z-x, y-x-y"

Tait–Bryan angles "x-y-z, y-z-x, z-x-y, x-z-y, z-y-x, y-x-z"

Most common usages is z-y-x in Tait-Bryan angles. "yaw" means rotate around z axis, "pitch" means rotate around y axis, "roll" means rotate around x axis.

If you use z-y-x order the euler-angles order is  [yaw, pitch, roll]. You must choose the order depending on what field you work in.